# How can I export a QuickTime File with Chapter Markers from iMovie HD?

Tags: itunes, video, imovie, quicktime

I have a video with chapter markers in iMovie HD 6.03 (267.2).

What settings do I need to use when exporting to get a file with chapter markers viewable by QuickTime and iTunes?.

Comment: Have you tried doing this?  I am fairly certain that the chapter markers would go into any of the quicktime/itunes filetypes.

Comment: I am pretty sure that @Jamie is right.

Comment: Unfortunately, I am pretty sure @Jamie is wrong because I just tried it.  Note that the OP is using iMovie 6, a very old version of iMovie.  I've never managed to make it export chapters to anything but iDVD.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you can do it using [Metadata Hootenanny](http://www.applesolutions.com/bantha/MH.html).

> > It allows you to edit and search the metadata that can be stored in  QuickTime movies (mov files), including chapters. Quicktime files support a large number of metadata options, but the QuickTime Player doesn't provide an easy way of accessing them. Metadata Hootenanny does.

You can read [this forum thread](http://forums.macnn.com/82/applications/324769/export-imovie-chapters/) for more info.